# Correctness of convergence proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

The problem is this :

> Given a sequence $\{x_k\}_{k = 1}^{\infty} \subset \mathbb{R}^n, x_k, x \neq 0$, define $y_k = \dfrac{x_k}{\|x_k\|}$. If $x_k \to x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then prove that $y_k \to \dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$.

My proof is as follows:
$x_k \to x \implies c_k := \dfrac{1}{\|x_k\|} \to \dfrac{1}{\|x\|}$. Now $x_k \to x$, so $y_k = c_kx_k \to \dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$ as $c_k \to \|x\|$.

This uses the fact that if $c_k \to c \in \mathbb{R}, x_k \to x \in \mathbb{R}^n \implies c_kx_k \to cx$, whose proof proceeds by using the fact that $c_k x_{k, i} \to cx_i$. But isn't this approach somewhat flawed, in that $c_k$, in our case, depends on all $x_{k, j}\ (j = 1, \ldots n)$.

Is it allowed to separate and work on individual convergences, instead of showing that the entire thing converges as a whole. I'm having kind of a conceptual block here.

Comment: You should probably specify that $x\ne0$.

Comment: Yes, it was specified $x_k, x \neq 0$. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c_{k}\rightarrow c$, for some $M>0$, $|c_{k}|\leq M$ for all $k=1,2,...$, so 
\begin{align*}
|c_{k}x_{k}-cx|&=|c_{k}x_{k}-c_{k}x+c_{k}x-cx|\\
&\leq|c_{k}|\cdot|x_{k}-x|+|x|\cdot|c_{k}-c|\\
&\leq M|x_{k}-x|+|x|\cdot|c_{k}-c|,
\end{align*}
now $M|x_{k}-x|+|x|\cdot|c_{k}-c|\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$, now use Squeeze Theorem to conclude that $c_{k}x_{k}\rightarrow cx$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that every norm in $\mathbf R^n$ is continuous, that is, $x_k \to x$ implies $\| x_k\| \to \|x\|$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assume that $x \neq 0$.

Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
\| {x \over \|x\|} - { x_n \over \|x_n\| } \| &=& \| { \|x_n\| x - \|x\| x_n \over \|x\| \|x_n\| }\|  \\
&\le& \| { \|x_n\| x - \|x_n\| x_n \over \|x\| \|x_n\| }\| + \| { \|x_n\| x_n - \|x\| x_n \over \|x\| \|x_n\| }\| \\
&\le & {1 \over \|x\| } \|x-x_n\| + {| \|x\|-\|x_n\| |\over \|x\| |} \\
&\le& {2 \over \|x\|} \|x-x_n\|
\end{eqnarray}
where I used $| \|x\|-\|x_n\|  | \le \|x-x_n\|$ on the last line.